# Dayjs round trip with TZ gives odd result

Tags: dayjs

I'm getting an unexpected result with this test:

```
it.only('should return a Dayjs with a truncated timestamp in the correct timezone', () => {
      const rfc3339Zulu = '2021-11-16T19:35:31.877656Z';
      const value = dayjs
        .utc(rfc3339Zulu, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')
        .tz('America/Los_Angeles');
      const isoZulu = value.toISOString();
      expect(isoZulu).to.be.equal('2021-11-16T19:35:31.877Z');
});
```

I get the result:

```
      AssertionError: expected '2021-11-16T20:35:31.877Z' to equal '2021-11-16T19:35:31.877Z'
```

An hour off.  Value is in PST (GMT-8):

```
M {
  '$L': 'en',
  '$u': false,
  '$d': 2021-11-16T19:35:31.877Z,
  '$x': { '$timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles' },
  '$y': 2021,
  '$M': 10,
  '$D': 16,
  '$W': 2,
  '$H': 11,
  '$m': 35,
  '$s': 31,
  '$ms': 877,
  '$offset': -480
}
```

Removing the TZ gives the expected result.   Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  This is an old bug.   Just update the dayjs module.